# How to fix error 'libxenlight failed to create a new domain'?

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, xen, virt-manager

Using Virt-Manager 1.2.1 on 14.04. / Xen 4.4 from repos. Cannot create VM machine because this error crops up on virt-manager.

This is after editing `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` to allow virt-manager to work and restarting libvirt and xen services.

Closest clue is [from the OpenSuse forums](https://forums.suse.com/archive/index.php/t-6023.html) which suggest Apparmor and libvirtd are in conflict. Solution seemed to be to disable Apparmor. Apparmor does not seem installed though.

Comment: Where is the virtual host installed?

Comment: On a local server. Not a cloud setup.

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, I was not seeing the trees due to the forest.  Never mind my last comment.

Comment: Better comment, have you tried this answer?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/466292/virt-manager-cant-connect-to-xen

Comment: Thanks. Yes, tried that link. Virt-manager does connect and works passed that point and gets stuck later down the line with above error. In short, didn't help.

Comment: It appears to be a permission issue. Others have raised this same issue. Have a look:\n https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1326003 \n http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-288781.html \

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1326003 | http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-288781.html | https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server/2014-June/006903.html | https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2014-April/msg00022.html | https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10276/internal-error-libxenlight-failed-to-create-new-domain/

Comment: Launchapad link adds a clue that pygrub might not have enough permissions. This is an old 2014 bug. Looks fixed. Maybe another file has been affected the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work. Yet to try.

So it looks like there is a need to add the following to a file named `usr.sbin.libvirtd`. In commandline, updatedb (`sudo updatedb`) and then use locate to find that file (`locate usr.sbin.libvirtd`).

Edit it with gedit or nano or vi or another applicable text editor

Under these lines:

```
/lib/udev/scsi_id PUx,
/lib/udev/scsi_id PUx,
/usr/lib/xen-common/bin/xen-toolstack PUx,
```

Add:

```
/usr/lib/xen-*/bin/pygrub PUx,
```

Taken by and large from:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1326003/comments/2